# Installing Enthought Canopy and Python(x,y) together returns an error

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, canopy, pythonxy

I have `Enthought Canopy` (Academic Version) now I want install `Python(x,y)` besides it. After installing it in both `Enthought Canopy` (after running a code) and `Python(x,y)` (when loading) I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have an architecture mismatch

Comment: So what should I do? I'm installing in different paths.

Comment: On Windows, it's fragile to install two Pythons that have the same version (e.g. 2.7) and bitness (e.g. 32 or 64-bit) on the same system. When you install Python on Windows, registry entries are set which can conflict. In addition, PythonXY might set environment variables `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH`, which would aggressively interefere with other Pythons including Canopy. What is your goal in installing both?